# ¿Como guardo una fecha en una variable externa en python?

Tags: python, tkinter, date, datetime

La duda era la siguiente, quiero seleccionar una fecha mediante la librería `tkcalendar`, se selecciona correctamente, pero no puedo usar la variable fuera de la función.

```
def dateentry_view():
    def print_sel():
        date = cal.get_date()
        print(date)
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Elige el día').pack()
    cal = DateEntry(top)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    ttk.Button(top, text="Aceptar", command=print_sel).pack()
```

Como puedo pasar la variable `date` para mostrarla en una `Label` de la siguiente manera:

```
labelFecha = Label(root,textvariable=fecha)
```

Comment: Si solo quieres obtener la fecha sca la variable de esa función ```print_sel()```y déjala en la otra

Comment: Bienvenido Darío c: labelFecha está dentro de la función `dateentry_view`?

Comment: @DanteS. no, está fuera

Comment: @christian tengo que declarar `fecha` pero no sé como hacerlo para que guarde bien la fecha de `date`